# Calculating Real Network Round-trip

Tags: networking, network-protocols

I would like to understand network latency a bit better.

Lets say there's one Client and two Servers. Client sends 1000 bytes to each of the Servers, each Server responds instantly with 1000 bytes.

Ping round trip times from Client:

- To **Server 1** - 2ms
- To **Server 2** - 20ms

Assume both Client and Servers are connected to quality 1 Gbps pipe (but not via dedicated line between them).

Question: how to calculate real time from when Client starts sending its 1000 bytes to when it fully receives the last byte of the response data. Will it be something close to 2ms for Server 1 and 20ms for Server 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly right!

The ping round-trip delay measures how long it takes a small packet of data to travel from one host on the network to another, and back to the original host.

You should keep in mind that the numbers you get fluctuate a bit based on network conditions and load on the processors of the hosts. You should average the round-trip delay over a few samples but be prepared that any other packet may experience an unusual delay for a variety of reasons.